# Check if button is enabled or not Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to check if button is enabled or disabled on the webpage. I have tried below methods but they all return true even if the button is disabled.

```
Boolean z = Driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen81")).isEnabled();
System.out.println(z);
Boolean y = Driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen72")).isEnabled();
System.out.println(y);
Boolean u = Driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen81")).isDisplayed();
System.out.println(u);
Boolean v = Driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen72")).isDisplayed();
System.out.println(v);
```

Also html text for button is same when it is enabled or disabled.

Can anyone please suggest any better idea.

Comment: <button id="ext-gen81" class="x-btn-text x-tbar-page-next" type="button"/>

Comment: If there is no change in html,  then CSS will change...  Observe the CSS property which is changing... And get that value using getCssProperty method...

Comment: Are you using extJS if yes which version

Answer (score -1):

From your comment

```
<button id="ext-gen81" class="x-btn-text x-tbar-page-next" type="button"/>
```

It looks like `ExtJS` Application.If so you can use the Selenium's `element.isEnabled()` to check whether element is enabled or not.For that you have to check the class attribute of the element and check whether it contains disabled css or not

The following snippet is specific for ExtJS element to check if it enabled or not.Because if element is disabled in ExtJS the class will have some of the css like`x-item-disabled x-disabled`. I guess it will help you.If not follow the same approach and change the regex to suit your needs

```
public static Boolean isElementEnabled(WebElement element) {
    String className = element.getAttribute("class");
    return className.matches(".+(x-.+-disabled)+");
}
```